# How do I set environment variables in a new Python Process

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-multiprocessing

I'm making a new process in Python using the `"spawn"` multiprocessing context

```
import multiprocessing
ctx = multiprocessing.get_context("spawn")

proc = ctx.Process(target=my_func)
proc.start()
```

I would like for this process to have a set of environment variables.  Ideally I would specify this when creating the process, like this:

```
proc = ctx.Process(target=my_func, environment={"MY_NAME": "MY_VALUE"})
```

Is there some way to do this?  I would like for the Python runtime to do this so that I can be ensured that these environment variables get set before any of my Python code runs.

Comment: What's wrong with the obvious answer? Either set the env vars before calling `ctx.Process()` or pass a function as as the `target` that sets the environment then calls `my_func`.

Comment: Some imports like pytorch use environment variables to determine the visible GPUs. Ideally, the context of the new process has these already set before anything is imported.

Answer (score 1):

You can access and set environment variables via the `os` package.

```
import os

print(os.environ)
os.environ['test'] = 1
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question I'm looking for the Python runtime to handle this before user code has a chance to proceed

Comment: @MRocklin, a little unclear.  You're looking for something more than, for instance, running what I wrote *prior* to the rest of your code?  Aside from placing the code in another program that you import and then run, I'm not clear how else you'd even envision Python would do this.  Assuming you don't want to simply create additional environment variables outside of Python, I'm not sure how you'd have variables available without setting them as part of the program.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing locally, you can export the variables into your local environment.

`export MY_NAME='Matt'`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm looking to change values dynamically when starting new processes from Python.